# Switch flexbox width to 50% when there are 4 child items

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to use flexbox to set up a grid display of images. Everything is working, and the layout looks nice, except when I have 4 images.

This is my current code for the images

```
section.flex-container .field-items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  align-items: stretch;
}
section.flex-container .field-items .field-item {
  display: inline;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 33%;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Is there any way that I can increase the width to 50% when 4 .field-items are present? Again, I only want the 50% with to occur when there are 4 images.

A demo can be found here on codepen: [Demo](http://codepen.io/mcgowanm89/pen/aNWOey)

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear. Please post enough code to reproduce the problem. Posting a demo may also be helpful (e.g., jsfiddle.net).

Comment: @Michael_B I've added a codepen demo

Comment: There may be something wrong with your SCSS preprocessing. When using the compiled CSS, the layout seems to work. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YqVyXO?editors=1100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this via sibling count, which is pretty rad if you've never used it before. You're may already be familiar with the pseudo-class `:nth-child` which lets you select something based on its position within a list of children.

> In comes `:nth-last-child`. The difference between the two is that
>   `nth-child` applies to the `nth child` counting from the top (ie, the
>   child that has n-1 elements before it) while the `nth-last-child`
>   applies to the `nth child` counting from the bottom (ie, the child that
>   has n-1 elements after it!). ([Original](http://andr3.net/blog/post/142) | [Follow-up](http://lea.verou.me/2011/01/styling-children-based-on-their-number-with-css3/))

Using the sibling count, you can then increase the width of your `.field-item` when it has 4 items like so:

```
section.flex-container {
  .field-items{
    .field-item {
      &:first-child:nth-last-child(4), &:first-child:nth-last-child(4) + .field-item {
        width:50%;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/angeliquejw/pen/eZWpaM?editors=0100)